# How do I create a list of lists of type Any?

Tags: kotlin

I have a bunch of lists of different types:

```
            var downloadSpeedMbpsList = mutableListOf<Double>()
            var uploadSpeedMbpsList = mutableListOf<Double>()
            var pingMsList = mutableListOf<Double>()
            var jitterMsList = mutableListOf<Double>()

            var rsrpList = mutableListOf<Double>()//create lists with rsrp, rsrq, level, and later, time. Add then into the value for a higher order list as a value pair
            var rsrqList = mutableListOf<Double>()
            var levelList = mutableListOf<Int>()
            var isRegisteredList = mutableListOf<Int>()
            var earfcnList = mutableListOf<Int>()
            var cellIDList = mutableListOf<Int>()
```

Now I want to add them to my list of lists. but I want the lists to be of type any; That is, lists of different types that I can still write to:

```
 val listOfLists : MutableList<MutableList<Any?>> =  mutableListOf(downloadSpeedMbpsList, uploadSpeedMbpsList, pingMsList, jitterMsList, rsrpList,rsrqList,levelList, isRegisteredList, earfcnList, cellIDList)
```

However, the above code gives me Type mismatch. It says that that right side is of type "out Any." How do I force the right side to type "Any?" ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because `Double` and `Int` aren't the same type, they have the same root which is `Number`, or you can also use `Any` which is less specific but that doesn't make it possible to have different lists based on different types have the same type in the end.

What you'll need is the `out` keyword to express hierarchy.

`val listOfLists : MutableList<MutableList<out Number?>>` works fine

`val listOfLists : MutableList<MutableList<out Any?>>` is OK too

More information:

- [Generics in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance)

Comment: The problem that I am getting is that once I use "out," I can no longer edit the objects in the lists. This won't work for me. Is there not a way to be able to declare a list of lists and also make it editable? Since a mutable list is by definition editable, out just nulls that.

Comment: @rickster26ter1 how are you planning to modify the object? No there is no way, because there is no way to identify whether a specific index is a list of `Double` or a list of `Int` but there might be workarounds, just need to know how you'll modify the objects

Answer (score 0):

[plusElement](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus-element.html) function does the trick:

```
val listOfLists = mutableListOf<MutableList<Any?>>()
    .plusElement(downloadSpeedMbpsList)
    .plusElement(uploadSpeedMbpsList)
    ...
```

Comment: I tried this. There's no longer a type mismatch, but listOfLists is of type "out Any"

Answer (score 0):

```
val listOfLists: MutableList<MutableList<*>> = mutableListOf(
    downloadSpeedMbpsList,
    uploadSpeedMbpsList,
    pingMsList,
    jitterMsList,
    rsrpList,
    rsrqList,
    levelList,
    isRegisteredList,
    earfcnList,
    cellIDList
)
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#star-projections

Additionaly - my comment about Any may be wrong, but can't you do this?

```
var downloadSpeedMbpsList = mutableListOf<Double>()
var uploadSpeedMbpsList = mutableListOf<Int>()

val listOfLists : MutableList<MutableList<out Any?>> = mutableListOf(
    downloadSpeedMbpsList,
    uploadSpeedMbpsList,
)

var list = listOfLists[0].toMutableList()
list.add(1.0)
listOfLists[0] = list

print(listOfLists)
```

Comment: I get the same problem as when I have "out Any". I can no longer edit the list.

Comment: If you specify out type you loose ability to edit that List. Why do you need to add return type of Any? I can query and add to list created as my example above.

Comment: return type of Any? makes the list editable still

Comment: `String` and `Int` are subtypes of `Any` (you can do `1 is Any` if you want to check) but `List<String>` is **not** a subtype of `List<Any>`, for complicated reasons - read the link on generics in @YassinHajaj's answer. Basically if you're going to create a list of "things that have this supertype but could be anything", you can only treat the contents as that supertype because that's all you can be sure of. `out Any` is a promise that you're only taking stuff *out* of the list (reading from it) and you'll only treat them as `Any` (which isn't a very useful type but hey). Check the link!

Answer (score 0):

> you don't need val listOfLists : MutableList<MutableList<Any?>>
>
> But

```
val listOfLists: MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf(
                downloadSpeedMbpsList,
                uploadSpeedMbpsList,
                pingMsList,
                jitterMsList,
                rsrpList,
                rsrqList,
                levelList,
                isRegisteredList,
                earfcnList,
                cellIDList)
```

> OR Create data class

```
 class Test() {
    var downloadSpeedMbpsList = mutableListOf<Double>()
    var uploadSpeedMbpsList = mutableListOf<Double>()
    var pingMsList = mutableListOf<Double>()
    var jitterMsList = mutableListOf<Double>()

    var rsrpList = mutableListOf<Double>()//create lists with rsrp, rsrq, level, and later, time. Add then into the value for a higher order list as a value pair
    var rsrqList = mutableListOf<Double>()
    var levelList = mutableListOf<Int>()
    var isRegisteredList = mutableListOf<Int>()
    var earfcnList = mutableListOf<Int>()
    var cellIDList = mutableListOf<Int>()

    val dataList = DataList(
            downloadSpeedMbpsList,
            uploadSpeedMbpsList,
            pingMsList,
            jitterMsList,
            rsrpList,
            rsrqList,
            levelList,
            isRegisteredList,
            earfcnList,
            cellIDList)

}

data class DataList(
        var downloadSpeedMbps : MutableList<Double> = mutableListOf(),
        var uploadSpeedMbps : MutableList<Double> = mutableListOf(),
        var pingMs : MutableList<Double> = mutableListOf(),
        var jitterMs : MutableList<Double> = mutableListOf(),

        var rsrp : MutableList<Double> = mutableListOf(),
        var rsrq : MutableList<Double> = mutableListOf(),
        var level : MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(),
        var isRegistered : MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(),
        var earfcn : MutableList<Int>  = mutableListOf(),
        var cellID : MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
)
```